# Having trouble understanding what exactly I am integrating for a hydrostatic force/pressure calculus question

Tags: calculus, integration

So the question is:

a trough has vertical ends that are trapezoids with parallel sides of length 4m (top) and 2m (bottom) and a height of 3m. If the trough is filled with water to a depth of 2m, find the force exerted on the water on one end of the trough.

I am just confused as to what exactly I am integrating. I know how to do it when the water is  full but am kind of confused as to what the implications of a trough that is not all the way.

If it is full I know that it is

$$\int _0^3\:pg\:\left(2x\right)\left(3-y\right)dy$$

But if it is filled until 2, am I still integrating from 0 to 3, or 2 to 3? Is it asking for the force exerted for the part submerged in the water or the whole thing? And what exactly does depth mean? Depth of the water or the trough?

I am assuming that since only the amount of water change, only the area I am integrating change. So would it be

$$\int _2^3\:ρg\:\left(2x\right)\left(3-y\right)dy$$

or is it

$$\int _0^2\:ρg\:\left(2x\right)\left(2-y\right)dy$$

ρ is the density of the fluid and g is the gravitational acceleration.

Comment: $p$? $g$? Are these tea bags? Yes, $2m$ is depth of water. The trough has depth $3m$.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I should have been specific in that they're density and gravitational acceleration. So would I be integrating the depth of the water or depth of the trough?

Comment: The $1m$ above the water level is air - it exerts negligible pressure. So my educated guess, as a humble mathematician - integral over [0, 2] - wouldn't you agree?

Comment: If y measures distance up from the bottom, then the second integral is correct, since a slice y units up from the bottom is $2-y$ units below the surface of the water.  (Now you need to express x in terms of y.)